# nodejs upload file HTTP POST

Tags: node.js

I want "client.js" to read a file, and upload it to a certain folder via "server.js" using HTTP POST. When file size is small(1kb), it works. But when file size is bigger(maybe around 100kb), it doesen't work. There is no error, but the stored image is less in size than what it's supposed to be. I don't know why. please help.

1.client.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http =  require('http');

postData = null;

postData=fs.readFileSync("test.jpg")

if(postData!=null){

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 10730,
  method: 'POST' 
};

var clientRequest = http.request(options);
clientRequest.end(postData);}
```

2.server.js

```
 var http =  require('http');
 var fs = require('fs');

 var server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
   req.on('data', (chunk)=>{
   fs.writeFile('testcopy.jpg',chunk)})
   req.on('end', ()=>{
   console.log("end")
 })})
 server.listen(10730,'localhost');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can use [busyboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-busboy) to upload file, i am using it in my project and i handle images of large size in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), a middleware that handles `multipart/form-data` it automatically save the file for you  and populates the req variable: 
`req.file //access file info`. It has a lot of functionalities that abstract this kind of work. You can define size of file, filter files and many other facilities, I know that multer is simple to use and works with [express](https://expressjs.com/) as a middleware but I think you can try this:

```
var http =  require('http');

var server = http.createServer((req,res)=>{
   upload(req, res, function (err) {
     if (err) {
        // An error occurred when uploading
        return
     }
     console.log('end')
      // Everything went fine
   })
})
server.listen(10730,'localhost');
```

Comment: Thank you for comment. I think I should use 'multer' as you said. But I just came to be curious about what is wrong with my code. Is there anyone who can explain the problem?